# make.names returns unexpected result after converting list to character vector

Tags: r

I am trying to create a character vector from a list of strings. My end goal is to pass this to `make.names()` to create column names for a dataframe.

```
temp<-data.frame(col1=c("use this row as name"),col2=c("use this row as name 2"))
make.names(temp[1,]) #fails
make.names(c("hi","xxx!@#$")) #works as expected
typeof(temp[1,])
typeof(c("hi","xxx!@#$"))

typeof(as.character(temp[1,]))
make.names(as.character(temp[1,]))
```

output:

```
> temp<-data.frame(col1=c("use this row as name"),col2=c("use this row as name 2"))
> make.names(temp[1,])
[1] "X1" "X1"
> make.names(c("hi","xxx!@#$"))
[1] "hi"      "xxx...."
> typeof(temp[1,])
[1] "list"
> typeof(c("hi","xxx!@#$"))
[1] "character"
> typeof(as.character(temp[1,]))
[1] "character"
> make.names(as.character(temp[1,]))
[1] "X1" "X1"
> temp[1,]
                  col1                   col2
1 use this row as name use this row as name 2
```

GOAL:

```
>colnames(temp) 
"use this row as name" "use this row as name 2"
```

in some form. Spacing and other formatting is unimportant as long as the column names are semi-understandable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just `unlist` your data frame:

```
make.names(unlist(temp))
[1] "use.this.row.as.name"   "use.this.row.as.name.2"
```

Keep in mind that some of your attempts were failing because `temp` is actually two columns of *factors*, combined with some slightly nonintuitive behavior when you call `as.character` on a list. (See `?as.character`).

Comment: That worked perfectly, I had to add `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` when reading in the csv and use the unlis command `make.names(unlist(temp[1,]))`